# How to perform reverse permute to an already permuted matrix?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, permutation

I had posted earlier a question about how to interleave R,G and B vectors here (
[How to form a vector from RGB matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27889402/how-to-form-a-vector-from-rgb-matrices)). I want to reverse the operation performed on the matrix. I tried the following code but im not able to get the input back.Since ipermute was the exact inverse of permute i tried using it.

```
C  = ipermute(H, [3 1 2])
```

I need to separate the permuted vectors and change it back into separate planes and then finally recombine the planes to get a 3 dimensional image.The following is the code that I used to permute the three planes.

```
 A=imread('C:\Users\Desktop\lena.jpg');

 R = A(:, :, 1);
 G = A(:, :, 2);
 B = A(:, :, 3);

 R1 = reshape(R.',1,[]);
 G1 = reshape(G.',1,[]);
 B1 = reshape(B.',1,[]);

 H = permute(A, [3 1 2]);

 N = numel(A)/3;
 V = H(1 : N);
 W = H(N + 1 : 2*N);
 X = H(2*N + 1 : end);
```

I need to reverse this operation entirely to get the orignal image that i've permuted.Please help thanks in advance.

Comment: What was your procedure to obtain `Dimg` from `A` ? I don't see `Dimg` in the code. Only if your `Dimg` is same as `H` you could obtain the original image.

Comment: Try `C = permute(Dimg, [2 3 1]);`

Comment: I've changed the question sir. Dimg and H are the same. But ipermute isnt working.

Answer (score 0):

> H2=ipermute([V,W,X],[3,1,2]);
>
> H3=reshape(H2,3,256,256);
>
> H4=ipermute(H3,[3,1,2]);

H4 is original A